# Zoom UIWebView in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, zooming

I have an UIWebView in an iOS 7 app that loads a webpage. I want to set the webview at zoom level 2.0 when the app is launched.

I initialize the webview as

```
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT-66)];
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.webView.opaque = NO;
```

Then in the viewDidAppear method, I set the zoom scale as

```
UIScrollView *sv = [[self.webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[sv setZoomScale:2.0f];
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me achieve this?

I cannot modify the html as it is an external page.

Comment: UIWebView has a scrollView property - don't try to traverse the view hierarchy to attempt to modify the scrollView. try [self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:2.0].

Comment: Tried that but it did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can set scalePageToFit = YES and setZoomScale. Try commenting out the scalePageToFit.

Comment: Tried that but taking out scalePageToFit=YES also takes out the ability to use pinch zoom on the website. Is there a way I can have both?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. You may have to add back in the pinch to zoom functionality yourself. I remember seeing it in the Stanford iTunes U iOS7 course. Sorry I'm not at home so I can't find the code.